# Exporting Image of the widget in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am creating a `GraphicsLayoutWidget` and then using `addPlot()` to add plots to the widget. This widget is not displayed on the screen but used to export image by using:

```
    exporter = pyqtgraph.exporters.ImageExporter(pwidget.scene())
    exporter.export(os.path.join(datadirtemp, str(typename) + '.png'))
```

But the images are never covering the whole plot.

Also, using the below item does not help:

```
exporter.parameters()['width'] = pwidget.scene().sceneRect().width()
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot export image with size=0 (requested export size is 0x0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to export the window before it is initialized. So you need to do

> QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

before exporting it.

Refer to the link: 
[from pyqtgraph's forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/t6pS2GLPrAs/QFQ_Z_bfQEQJ)